# Как остановить schedule в python

Tags: python

Есть такой кусочек кода, взятый из документации. Каждые 10 минут выводится сообщение. Если я в режиме отладки меняю время (не 10 а 6 мин) не перезапуская проект, то получается что расписания накладываются друг на друга (сообщение начинает выводится через 6 и 10 минут одновременно).
Как можно остановить выполнение предыдущего расписания, и запустить только текущее, если у него поменялся интервал времени?

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте:

```py
schedule.cancel_job(job)
```

[Документация](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.cancel_job)

**UPD:**

***Пример:***

```py
import schedule
import time


def job():
    print("Hello, World!")


def fun():
    print('Spam!')

job1 = schedule.every().seconds.do(job)

for i in range(3):
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

schedule.cancel_job(job1)
job2 = schedule.every().seconds.do(fun)

for i in range(3):
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

***stdout:***

```html
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Spam!
Spam!
```